# Polynomial Root Neighbourhood

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Can anyone offer any suggestions/hints as to what happens in a root neighbourhood of a polynomial?

Any advice would be a great help, I don't know if I'm just looking too deep and missing something obvious.

Comment: the function crosses the abscissa at the root, is this your question?

Comment: @carlos: the function crosses the abscissa  only if the root has odd multiplicity.

Comment: Interesting question.  Maybe you can examine how some polynomial root bounds change for polynomials in the root neighborhood.  E.g. how do the Gershgoren circles change among the polynomials in the neighborhood?

Comment: I suppose you could also plot the basins of attraction for your root finding algorithm for a few polynomials in the neighborhood.  I'd assume that if overlaid, the nonfractal looking portion of the joint basins of attraction gets smaller.